# Tkinter entry box is not defined when it appears for multiple windows

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, nameerror

I am trying to write code, where depending on the user input of the first window, another one pops up. However, the variable "r" appears on multiple secondary windows

So the user selects the configuration they want and the corresponding window to input their value pops up. If the user chooses "groove" I get a:
`NameError: name 'r_entry' is not defined` for line 20,
if the user chooses "groove" the same error for line 9.

Why is this happening? And how can this be solved?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

def gradation_enter_data():
    global r
    r=r_entry.get()

    if r:    
        gradationmenu.destroy()

    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Error", message="Provide values for all entry boxes!")
        return

def groove_enter_data():
    global r
    r=r_entry.get()

    if r:
        groovemenu.destroy()

    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Error", message="Provide values for all entry boxes!")
        return

def configuration_match_function():

    match configuration:
        case "groove":
            #GUI 
            groovemenu = tkinter.Tk()
            groovemenu.title("Groove Dimensions Data Entry")

            frame = tkinter.Frame(groovemenu)
            frame.pack()

            #DIMENSIONS
            dimensions_frame =tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Dimensions")
            dimensions_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            r_label = tkinter.Label(dimensions_frame, text="r:")
            r_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

            r_entry = tkinter.Entry(dimensions_frame)
            r_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

            for widget in dimensions_frame.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

            # ENTER DATA BUTTON
            button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Enter Data", command=groove_enter_data)
            button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=10)

            groovemenu.mainloop()

        case "gradation":
            #Gradation
            #GUI 
            gradationmenu = tkinter.Tk()
            gradationmenu.title("Gradation Dimensions Data Entry")

            frame = tkinter.Frame(gradationmenu)
            frame.pack()

            #DIMENSIONS
            dimensions_frame =tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Dimensions")
            dimensions_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            r_label = tkinter.Label(dimensions_frame, text="r:")
            r_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

            r_entry = tkinter.Entry(dimensions_frame)
            r_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)

            for widget in dimensions_frame.winfo_children():
                widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

            # ENTER DATA BUTTON
            button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Enter Data", command=gradation_enter_data)
            button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=10)

            gradationmenu.mainloop()

def enter_data():
    global configuration
    try:
        if(y.get()==0):
            configuration="groove"
        elif(y.get()==1):
            configuration="gradation"
        else:
            raise Exception("Something went wrong")
    except Exception as ex:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Error!", message=ex)
        return

    window.destroy()
    configuration_match_function()

#GUI 

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Stress Data Entry")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

#SHAFT CONFIGURATION

configuration_frame =tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Shaft Configuration")
configuration_frame.grid(row= 1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)

configuration_option=["Groove", "Gradation"]

y=IntVar()

for index in range(len(configuration_option)):
    radiobutton= Radiobutton(configuration_frame, 
    text=configuration_option[index], 
    variable=y, 
    value=index,
    padx=20,
    pady=10,
    )

for widget in configuration_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=5)

# ENTER DATA BUTTON
button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Enter Data", command=enter_data)
button.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="news", padx=20, pady=10)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `r_entry` is only defined as local variable in `configuration_match_function`. Declare it as `global` to be available in other functions.

Comment: Do I need to do this though? What I thought the point was, ``` r_entry```  would only appear as a local variable since, it only appears for each window temporarily and then gets assigned to the global ``` r``` . Still it doesn't work after declaring ``` r_entry```  as global

Comment: Do I need to declare it as a global variable each time it appears for a function?

Comment: You have to declare it as global in each function where the variable is **set**. In the shown code this is only `configuration_match_function`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for clearing that up. However still don't understand, why does it have to be declared as global, since it's designated to be a local variable(it only appears for the purpose of each window individually and the gets assigned to global r)?

Comment: A local variable exists only during a function invocation and is only accessible in this function (here `configuration_match_function`). The variable already ceased to exist when a `..._enter_data` function is called which tries to access the variable.

Comment: Instead of a global variable there are other options like adding it as parameter to the `..._enter_data` functions and using `lambda` or `functools.partial` to adapt the function to the `command` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to do was add `global r_entry` at the `configuration_match_function()`. This is because the variable `r_entry` is assigned to global `r` in a whole different function (i.e. `groove_enter_data()`), so it remained non defined between those 2 functions.
The code would look something like:

```
....
def configuration_match_function():
    global r_entry

    match configuration:
        case "groove":
....
```